# Not able to poll / fetch all records from kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to poll data from a specific topic like kafka is receiving 100 records/s
but most of the time it does not fetch all records.
I am using timeout as 5000ms and I am calling this method every `100ms`
Note : I am subscribing to the specific topic too

**@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "100")**

```
    public void pollRecords() {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = 
        leadConsumer.poll("5000");
```

How can I fetch all the data from kafka ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximum number of records returned from poll() is specified with `max.poll.records` consumer config parameter.  (default is 500) Also, there are another consumer config parameters which limits the maximum amount of data returned from server. (`fetch.max.bytes` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes`)

On the other hand, on broker side there is another size limit which is called `message.max.bytes`.

So you should set these parameters properly to get more messages.

From Kafka docs ([link](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)):

> **max.poll.records:** The maximum number of records returned in a single
>   call to poll(). (default: 500)
>
> **fetch.max.bytes:** The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. Records are fetched in batches by the
>   consumer, and if the first record batch in the first non-empty
>   partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch
>   will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress.
>   As such, this is not a absolute maximum. The maximum record batch size
>   accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker
>   config) or max.message.bytes (topic config). Note that the consumer
>   performs multiple fetches in parallel. (default:52428800)
>
> **message.max.bytes:** The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka. If this is increased and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the
>   consumers' fetch size must also be increased so that the they can
>   fetch record batches this large. In the latest message format version,
>   records are always grouped into batches for efficiency. In previous
>   message format versions, uncompressed records are not grouped into
>   batches and this limit only applies to a single record in that
>   case.This can be set per topic with the topic level max.message.bytes
>   config. (default: 1000012)
>
> **max.partition.fetch.bytes:** The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. Records are fetched in batches
>   by the consumer. If the first record batch in the first non-empty
>   partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still
>   be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. The maximum
>   record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via
>   message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config).
>   See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the consumer request size. (default: 1048576)