# Kafka config MAX_BYTES still being limited by 500 messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have my consumer configured like so:

The problem is when I poll my data from test topic (1 partition containing 1000 messages), I'm only getting 500 messages per poll. Each message is roughly 90 bytes a piece. This config should definitely be high enough to handle all the data. Any reason why this would be?

#### Consume Configuration

```
    public static KafkaConsumer<String, SpecificRecordBase> createConsumer(
            Arguments args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, args.bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, args.groupId);
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "4500");

        // Data batching configuration
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");

        // Specify the number of bytes you want to read in batch
        properties.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
        properties.setProperty(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, args.schemaRegistryUrl);

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    }
```

#### Polling Piece

```
.....
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, SpecificRecordBase> records =
                        myConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(CONSUMER_POLL_SECONDS));
....
```

Record count here is 500

Edit:

Read in docs that default poll count is 500. Which config should I need? I don't really care about number of messages, I care about the amount of bytes I'm streaming.

```
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "500000000");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "500000000");
```

Comment: MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG is what you want, but don't make it millions of records

Answer (score 2):

There is a consumer config property `max.poll.records` left you did not change from its default value which is 500.

> If you are using the Java consumer, you can also adjust max.poll.records to tune the number of records that are handled on every loop iteration.

refer to: [Confluent Kafka Consumer Properties](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html)

I remember me having a similar issue but in my case the problem was caused by one of the byte limitations.

Comment: @Rern Oh, I am sorry. Did not see your edit when answering. Did `ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG` solve your problem?

Comment: It did, thanks. Curious about the follow-up regarding if I need to update all of those settings

Answer (score 1):

To complete.

It seems you want to control exactly the amount of bytes the broker will send to your consumer. Indeed you need to play with the following parameters  :

```
FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG
```

==> The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request.

```
FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG
```

==> The maximum amount of data the broker should return for a fetch request. Keep in mind that, if the first batch of record of the first non empty partition has a size greater than this value, the broker will still return it ( to let the consumer progress). This is not an absolute maximum.

```
FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG
```

==> The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy.
Should be less than or equal to the timeout used in poll(timeout)
Playing with this param might be efficient if you want to control the size you're streaming, but will add latency.

```
MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG
```

==> The maximum number of records returned for a fetch request. As already explained in other answer, this parameter is important if you want to control the size of the broker answers.

If `S` is the expected payload size, and `s` the average expected size of your records, you should be sure that MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG > `S`/`s`

Keep in mind that the more control you want over the size of the payload ( records), the more latency you might incur ( by increasing `FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems configs in consumer side is okay. But you should also consider broker configs. In broker side there is another size limit which is called `message.max.bytes`. You should increase it too.

From Kafka docs:

> **message.max.bytes:** The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka. If this is increased and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the
>   consumers' fetch size must also be increased so that the they can
>   fetch record batches this large. In the latest message format version,
>   records are always grouped into batches for efficiency. In previous
>   message format versions, uncompressed records are not grouped into
>   batches and this limit only applies to a single record in that
>   case.This can be set per topic with the topic level max.message.bytes
>   config. (default: 1000012)

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667286/10550738) for more information.